# Angularjs filter with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I have the following regex to match a URL:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

I need to apply this to a filter so it only matches and grabs the URL from a value:

I want to add it to this part in particular:

```
return arr[i].text;
```

**Filter**

```
    app.filter('getFirstCommentFrom',function(){
  return function(arr, user){
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
      if(arr[i].from.username==user)
        return arr[i].text;
    }
    return '';
  }
})



{{p.comments.data|getFirstCommentFrom:'machinas_test'}}
```

Not sure how to add this.

Comment: What have you actually tried to get the match from this regex?

Comment: provide a test url and what you expect the filter result to return.

Answer (score 0):

To start, something like this

```
app.filter('getFirstCommentFrom',function(){
  var regex = /^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/

  return function(arr, user){
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      if(arr[i].from.username==user){
        return arr[i].text.replace(regex, SOMETHINGHERE);
      }
    }
    return '';
  }
});
```